# ¿Se pueden escribir registros al mismo tiempo en SQLite desde una aplicación desarrollada en windows form que trabaja en red?

Tags: c#, sqlite

me podrían ayudar por favor en la siguiente duda.

Actualmente estoy retomando el desarrollo local, siempre he utilizado windows form y SQL Server, solo que algunos usuarios al instalar más de un programa les resulta incómodo, investigando encontré SQLite, me parece muy buena alternativa para un proyecto de una tienda comercial, solo que esta tienda utiliza 8 cajas simultáneamente, aquí es donde entra mi duda si las 8 cajeras podran escribir en la base de datos simultáneamente cuando se estén registrando las ventas, espero que me puedan ayudar a salir de esta duda y si realmente es recomendable utilizar SQLite en un sistema que estará manejando estas transacciones.

Comment: No me queda claro tu escenario, si estas trabajando con winforms....como planeas conectar las 8 cajas a SQLite?

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, visita https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour -> enlace altamente recomendado. A ver si entiendo, ¿quieres que las 8 cajeras tengan su propio archivo de base de datos `SQLite`? En caso sea "recomendado", aquí unas preguntas: ¿cómo manejarías el inventario? ¿cómo harías si habilitan una 9na cajera? ¿y si la tienda abre una sucursal? ¿y qué ocurre si se les malogra un ordenador y pierden 1 base de datos de las 8 que están en funcionamiento, cómo haces para recuperar la data sin parar el negocio?. Ahora, dicho todo esto, ¿estás seguro que quieres ir por ese camino?

Comment: Si estas pensando en una base centralizada multi usuarios, si bien sqlite soporta múltiples conexiones, no creo que sea recomendable en tu escenario, yo iría por algún motor más clásico para esto, un postgres, mysql, sql-server, etc.

Comment: Hola, revisa este link creo que habla de lo mismo:
[Sqlite on cloud base in Livecode for centralized database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072590/sqlite-on-cloud-base-in-livecode-for-centralized-database)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Si todas las cajas acceden a la misma base de datos de SQLite. El archivo de base de datos de SQLite tendría que estar en una carpeta compartida de la red. Pero esta configuración está desaconsejada.

De la documentación oficial de SQLite https://www.sqlite.org/useovernet.html

> the SQLite library is not tested in across-a-network scenarios, nor is
> that reasonably possible. Hence, use of a remote database is done at
> the user's risk.

En realidad una base de datos de SQLite debería accederse desde una única máquina y residir en el sistema de archivos local de esa máquina.

Así que en tu escenario, para usar correctamente una base de datos de SQLite, deberías poner una máquina con un servidor web donde implementaras una Web API que fuera la única que accediera a la base de datos y las cajas llamaran a este Web API.

Otra alternativa sería poner un servidor de base de datos cliente/servidor como SQL Server, Postgres, etc. y las cajas accedieran a este servidor de base de datos.

Si tu principal preocupación es tener una instalación lo más simple posible, es decir, necesitar sólamente instalar la aplicación de caja, una solución es usar bases de datos en la nube. Hay muchísimas alternativas tanto en AWS como en Azure.